# Kendo UI for MVC - TreeView - select only child nodes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I have a problem with onSelect function of my TreeView. The onSelect function (respectively the ajax call inside the onSelect function) should only trigger on non-expandable nodes. I tried it with a simple if-condition around the ajax call, but it seems like this doesn't work the way I intended. 
How can I achieve my goal?

```
function onSelect(e) {
    selectedTable = e.node.textContent;
    rows = $("#dropdownrows").val();

    if(e.node.hasChildren){

      $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/Editor/DataTable',
          data: { tableName: slectedTable, tablePart: rows },
          success: function (data) {
              $("#db").html(data);
          }
      });
    }
}
```

My TreeView looks like this:

```
Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                .Name("treeview")
                .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>) ViewBag.treeView)
                .Events(events => events
                    .Select("onSelect")
                )
```

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used

```
function onSelect(e) {
    selectedTable = e.node.textContent;
    rows = $("#dropdownrows").val();
    if (e.node.childElementCount == 1) {
        alert("called");
    }
}
```